# Выбор поля из таблицы, связанного с другими таблицами

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Есть 3 таблицы:
**Table1** : *id | name | source*
**Table2** : *id | name*
**General** : id | element_id | type
Суть в том, что в **General** лежат строки в определенной последовательности (последовательность важна), где element_id это *id* из **Table1** или **Table2** а *type* определяет к какой из таблиц относится строка (0 - **Table1**, 1 - **Table2**).
Как сделать выборку из таблицы **General** чтобы на выходе получить нечто подобное?
Или есть более удобный способ хранить данные?
Изначально казалось, что вариант **General** : id | table1_id | table2_id не подойдет, так как одно из полей всегда будет *null*.

```
element_id | name
22         | test
58         | Joe
22         | hello
(здесь element_id = 22 не одна и та же строка,  
а одна из них принадлежит Table1, другая Table2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или есть более удобный способ хранить данные?

Именно так! Таблицы `Table1` и `Table2` объединить, поле `type` перенести в эту объединенную таблицу. Останется один простой джойн.

Таблицы:

```
one_table: id | name | source | type
general : id | element_id
```

Запрос:

```
select g.element_id, t.name
  from general g 
       join one_table t on t.id = g.element_id
```

> здесь `element_id = 22` не одна и та же строка, а одна из них принадлежит `Table1`, другая `Table2`

Если у вас сейчас встречаются одинаковые `id` в таблицах `Table1` и `Table2`, придется один раз сгенерировать заново при объединении.

Comment: Думаю это действительно наиболее правильный вариант, но насколько правильно то, что при объединении в одну таблицу в некоторых записях поле source будет иметь null ?

Comment: А что плохого в `null`? Пусть будет.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:
select ... from General, Table1, Table2 where (General.element_id=Table1.Id and General.type=1) or (General.element_id=Table2.Id and General.type=2)
Возможно, работать будет медленнее.
Одинаковые id в Table 1 и 2 лучше б в любом случае убрать, как по мне. Не знаю, что именно у вас за база, так что конкретно не скажу.
Структуру вам уже посоветовали. В вашем случае, возможно, стоит так и сделать — хрен с им, с лишним полем source. Если набор полей для разных типов сильно различается, стоит, имхо, сделать таблицу с общим набором и дополнительные для каждого типа. А в качестве поля связи везде использовать id из центральной таблицы.